# Не могу релизовать поиск на сайте Mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

При нажатии на поиск показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
все остальное нормально работает только поиск.

```
class DB {
  private static $connection;

  public static

  function getInstance() {
    if (self::$connection === null) {
      self::$connection = new\ mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
      self::$connection - > query('SET NAMES UTF8');
      if (self::$connection - > errno) {
        die("Error while connect to MySql");
      }
    }
    return self::$connection;
  }


  private

  function __clone() { //запрещаем клонирование объекта модификатором private
  }

  protected

  function __wakeup() {

  }

  public

  function __construct() {
    $this - > db = DB::getInstance();
  }

  /**
   * @param $sql
   * @return array|bool|\mysqli_result
   */
  public

  function query($sql) {
    $result = $this - > db - > query($sql);
    if (is_bool($result)) {
      return $result;
    }
    $data = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    if (!$data) {
      return false;
    }
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Я выделил в какой строке показывает ошыбку (46)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Метод запроса в базу данных:**

```
public function search($text)
{
   $text=$this->db->escape($text);
   $result=$this->db->query("SELECT FROM $this->table WHERE `title` LIKE '$text%'");
   print_r ($result);
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: этот вопрос, похоже, будет задаваться вечно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, проблема в большом количестве подключений к базе, а остальное вторично.

Comment: @Visman  да, возможно. не посмотрел, что тут не сЫнглтонЪ

Comment: А как правильно сделать подскажите????

Comment: А-а-а.... *выбивает*

Answer (score 1):

При каждом обращении к методам класса Db вызывается твой магический метод __construct . Сделай его обычным методом **protected function connect() {}**
И return делать не надо, т.к. ты в теле метода уже присваиваешь результат подключения, который используешь в других методах.
И может пригодится [mysqli:construct](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php)